miniznc how to force at least n number of occurrences of an element in an array
The problem statement is that I need to ensure there are at least 2 subsequent occurrences of some element in an array
For understanding let's assume we pick the number 1
therefore, this implies if the number 1 occurs anywhere in the array it must be followed by another 1 at least once or could be followed by it multiple times.
Would appreciate if anyone could help me with this. Not sure if any globals could be used to make this simpler
e.g.

[1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
[1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
[2, 3, 1, 1, 4, 5, 6, 7, 1, 1]

are all valid answers.
Where as

[0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
[2, 1, 3, 4, 5, 1, 8, 9, 9, 1]

are invalid
I've tried writing the code as follows but this constraint doesn't hold for the condition where it can have multiple 1's. The code I've provided just assumes there will be 2 occurrences only
% Define the array
int: n = 10; % Length of the array
array[1..n] of var 0..5: arr; % Example array with various numbers including '1'
 

constraint forall(i in 1..n-1)
(

if i mod 2 ==0
then 
arr[i-1]==1 <-> arr[i] == 1
endif

);


constraint arr[1]=1;

solve satisfy;

output [show(arr)];


Using the exists predicate, you could solve your (original) requirements as follows:
% Define the array
int: n = 10; % Length of the array
array[1..n] of var 0..5: arr; % Example array with various numbers including '1'

int: klen = 2; %  number of adjacent elements equal to k
int: k = 4;

%  predicates are defined to improve readability of the constraints

%  true, iff i points to the first k elements in a streak of elements
predicate IsFirstK(1..n: i) =
  (arr[i] == k) /\ ((i == 1) \/ (arr[i-1] != k));
  
%  true, iff the next len elements after i have value k
predicate HasKFollowers(1..n: i, 0..n: len) =
  ((len < 1) \/
   ((i < n-1) /\ (arr[i+1] == k) /\ 
    HasKFollowers(i+1, len-1)));
  
%  true, if element i has value k and predecessor is
%  also a k element
%  caller has to make sure that k > 1
predicate IsKFollower(1..n: i) =
  (arr[i] == k) /\ (arr[i-1] == k);
  
%  any occurrence of k belongs to klen or more elements
%  with value k
constraint forall(i in 1 ..n)
(
  (arr[i] != k) \/ 
  (IsFirstK(i) /\ HasKFollowers(i, klen-1)) \/
  ((i > 1) /\ IsKFollower(i))
);

%  there is at least one streak of klen or more
%  consecutive elements with value k in the array

%  compact form
%  constraint 
%  exists([ forall([ arr[j + i - 1] == k | i in 1..klen ]) | j in 1..n-klen+1]);

%  verbose form
constraint exists(j in 1..n-klen+1)
(
  forall(i in 1..klen)
  (
    arr[j + i - 1] == k
  )
);

The inner forall makes sure that all klen elements are equal to k.
The outer exists enforces that there is a block of klen elements.
The avoidance of streaks with fewer than klen elements with value k turned out to be complicated. I introduced predicates with meaningful names to keep the model comprehensible.
Predicate HasKFollowers even resorted to recursion to count the length of consecutive k elements.

I apologize for the delayed response.
Suppose we consider the same model you presented, but with two extra constraints to check if the constraint holds, i.e.
"constraint arr[3] = 1" and "constraint arr[5] = 4".
We get the following output: "arr = [4, 4, 1, 0, 4, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]", which should be invalid because a 4 is present in the array without a subsequent occurrence.
The model must enforce that if an element x appears anywhere in the array, it must have at least two subsequent occurrences.
Expected output should be
arr = [4, 4, 1, 0, 4, 4 0, 0, 0, 0]
